# WatchKit Force Menu Custom Icons Blurry

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit

I'm creating custom icons for the WatchKit Force Menu.  The documentation says to use an 80 x 80 size image with a drawing area of 54px square.  All that works fine, but my image, when displayed in the button, looks very blurry compared to the built-in button images.

I'm creating them in Illustrator at 80px square.  Saving as a .png image like the documentation says.  Sizing is correct when saved at 72 dpi.  If I do anything higher it causes the image in the button to be too large.  I cannot find a way to scale the image.

Has anyone run into this?  It seems like I would want to use a higher resolution image here or vector graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to save the file with `@2x` in the filename to support retina displays.

So if your filename is `myicon.png` rename it to `myicon@2x.png`. In code you just use `myicon` for the name, Xcode automatically picks the correct size.

For iPhone 6, `@3x` is required...

I would recommend to use the `Images.xcassets` in Xcode for maintaining all images. There are templates for all needed resolutions (@1x, @2x, @3x, ...). Create the icons in these several resolutions and drag the files from finder to the placeholders. Later in your code you simply use the name of the image set in Xcassets.

[image]

Comment: Why does whether you have an iPhone 5 or 6 affect the icons displayed on the Watch?

Comment: @Rawling: It does not. This is a generic description on how to deal with xcassets. Sorry for confusion